# Automate *.run file install?

Tags: centos, automation, installer, cuda

Using: `CentOS 6.2`
`BASH Script`

I regularly install `CUDA` (a GPU programming API) on machines in my work cluster, and have to reupgrade three `*.run` installers whenever I do an upgrade version-wise.

The installers are semi-predictably named (though NVIDIA sometimes changes up the naming scheme) so I've created a script that switches to the root user, takes the run level down to `3` to turn off any running X server instances, calls the most RECENT version in my installers directory with sh `ls -t base_<name>*.run|head -n 1` 
and then finally switches the run level back to `5`.

Now this is nice as it reduces intervention, but what I really would love to do is automatically input the enter/arrow sequences to the *.run autonomously from the script, as they're the exact same every time.  Is there a good way to do this for `*.run` files??  You don't have to give me a full answer even, just pointing me towards a good tutorial would be educational.

Also, on the odd chance someone with `CUDA` experience sees this, any idea if there's a repository that I can get the latest dev drivers; gpu tools installer (nvcc, etc.); and gpu SDK from? (these are my three *.run installers)  I can go in my browser and download all of these, but a command line scriptable way would be super nice as then I'd cut out one more step! :)

Comment: Have you tried passing `-h` or `--help` to see if you can use arguments to automate it?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Typing this (plus `sh` gave a "Getting" and "Running" section.  The part that sounds promising was in the `Running` section which says that option `--` results in `Following arguments will be passed in the embedded script`.  Assuming this is what I need, how do I tell what those argument are?

Comment: Try passing `-- -h` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try coding up an [Expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) script to handle this. I'm not sure if it can do arrow keys, but I've used it to automate command line inputs to commands/scripts in the past. These links may be useful if you go that route.

- http://oreilly.com/catalog/expect/chapter/ch03.html
- http://wiki.tcl.tk/11583
- http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/01/expect-expressions-loops-conditions/

Comment: Ah your answer is perfect... It will handle everything besides the driver.... actually knowing what to search for, I even found a post explaining how to do this:
http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=195758

Comment: I'm glad that helped. I've used it for a few scripts and I'd feel so lost without it. It's a great tool IMO.